# [Environment]::Is64BitProcess and [Environment]::Is32BitProcess is returning nothing

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I was trying to use PowerShell to detect the architecture of a computer - 32bit or 64bit.

I used to use this condition, for 64 bit:

```
if ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess -ne [Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem){}
```

I used to use this condition, for 32 bit:

```
if ([Environment]::Is32BitProcess -ne [Environment]::Is32BitOperatingSystem){}
```

But recently it was not working on a PC, so I tried debugging it, and it was failing everything single time. So I opened the PowerShell and tried to get what it returns for these commands. Turns out it doesn't return any `Environment` scope variables.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening, and how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: The `Is64BitProcess` and `Is64BitOperatingSystem` property was introduced in .NET Framework 4.0. Windows PowerShell 2.0 on Vanilla Windows 7 runs on .NET Framework 2.0. Upgrade to [a newer version of Windows Management Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616) (or, preferably, a supported version of Windows), to get a version of PowerShell that can access these properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a small helper function that uses `[Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem`, but if not available, reverts to WMI:

```
function Get-Architecture {
    # What bitness does Windows use
    switch ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {   # needs .NET 4
        $true  { 64; break }
        $false { 32; break }
        default {
            (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -replace '\D'
            # Or do any of these:
            # (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -replace '\D' -replace '86', '32'
            # (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).AddressWidth   # this is slow...
        }
    }
}

Get-Architecture  # returns either `64` or `32`
```

To also have it return the bitness of the PowerShell process, you can expand it to

```
function Get-Architecture {
    # What bitness does Windows use
    $windowsBitness = switch ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {   # needs .NET 4
        $true  { 64; break }
        $false { 32; break }
        default {
            (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture -replace '\D'
            # Or do any of these:
            # (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).SystemType -replace '\D' -replace '86', '32'
            # (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).AddressWidth   # slow...
        }
    }

    # What bitness does this PowerShell process use
    $processBitness = [IntPtr]::Size * 8
    # Or do any of these:
    # $processBitness = $env:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -replace '\D' -replace '86|ARM', '32'
    # $processBitness = if ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) { 64 } else { 32 }

    # return the info as object
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        'ProcessArchitecture' = "{0} bit" -f $processBitness
        'WindowsArchitecture' = "{0} bit" -f $windowsBitness
    }
}
```